# Getting permission denied when trying to run a shell script on jenkins pipeline

Tags: linux, jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to set a Jenkins pipeline to build an Ionic app inside a Linux server (ec2 instance on amazon services) My first stage inside the jenkinsfile is to run `npm install`, but it returns permission denied.

I've tried setting permissions to the folder using:

`chmod 777 /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin`

I've also tried adding the Jenkins user to the group that also has permissions. none of these seemed to work.

This is my Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
   agent any
      environment {
         PATH='/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin'
      }
   stages {

   stage('NPM Setup') {
          steps { sh '/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/npm install' }
   }

   stage('Android Build') {
       steps {
          sh 'ionic cordova build android --release'
       }
   }

   stage('APK Sign') {
   steps {
    echo "Sign Android APK Action"
   }
   }

   stage('Zip APK') {
     steps {
    echo "Zip the APK Action"
   }
  }

 }
}
```

I get this output

```
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (NPM Setup)
[Pipeline] sh
+ /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/npm install
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/p-ionic4_borderapp_ionic4_master@tmp/durable-9b0ecc49/script.sh: line 1: /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/npm: Permission denied
```

Comment: what does `stat /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/npm` say?

Comment: `File: ‘/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/npm’ -> ‘../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js’
  Size: 38         Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 10301h/66305d Inode: 1413811     Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/ec2-user)   Gid: ( 1000/ec2-user)
Access: 2019-07-29 16:35:46.370731900 +0000
Modify: 2019-05-28 21:36:25.000000000 +0000
Change: 2019-07-29 16:35:46.370731900 +0000
 Birth: `

Comment: So that's a symbolic link. And how about the file it links to?

Comment: `File: ‘/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js’
  Size: 4566       Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 10301h/66305d Inode: 1647403     Links: 1
Access: (0775/-rwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/ec2-user)   Gid: ( 1000/ec2-user)
Access: 2019-07-29 16:35:46.230734054 +0000
Modify: 2019-05-11 08:05:38.000000000 +0000
Change: 2019-07-29 16:35:46.230734054 +0000
 Birth:-`

Comment: And what about each of the directories permissions on the way to that file? And please, add that info to your question (edit it!) - the formatting in comments is suboptimal ...